# CakePHP select default value in SELECT input

Tags: php, cakephp, relationships, helper, cakephp-2.x

Using CakePHP:

I have a many-to-one relationship, let's pretend it's many Leafs to Trees.  Of course, I baked a form to add a Leaf to a Tree, and you can specify which Tree it is with a drop-down box ( tag) created by the form helper.

The only thing is, the SELECT box always defaults to Tree #1, but I would like it to default to the Tree it's being added to:

For example, calling `example.com/leaf/add/5` would bring up the interface to add a new Leaf to Tree #5.  The dropdown box for `Leaf.tree_id` would default to "Tree 5", instead of "Tree 1" that it currently defaults to.

What do I need to put in my Leaf controller and Leaf `view/add.ctp` to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should never use `select()`, or `text()`, or `radio()` etc.; it's terrible practice. You should use `input()`:

```
$form->input('tree_id', array('options' => $trees));
```

Then in the controller:

```
$this->data['Leaf']['tree_id'] = $id;
```

Comment: I'm not sure about "terrible practice"

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit better? Where is that variable `$tree` defined? Isn't `$options` supposed to be an array with key the type of the option?

Comment: Believes what he says Miles, is a TERRIBLE practice, i've spent 2:00 hours of my life traying to set the "after" attribute of Cake with a $this->Form->Select() and it doesn't work fine. In order to save valuable time use $this->Form->input as a Select.

Comment: Agreed; for whatever reason, cakePHP totally doesn't care for the select().

Comment: There is a time to use input and a time to use select etc.

Answer (score 54):

In CakePHP 1.3, use `'default'=>value` to select the default value in a select input:

```
$this->Form->input('Leaf.id', array('type'=>'select', 'label'=>'Leaf', 'options'=>$leafs, 'default'=>'3'));
```

Comment: Why this is not marked as answer? This is the correct one (the other could be a suggestion, but this is the real answer about the question!)

Comment: This is correct in cake 1.2 as well. To stop yourself from going mad - don't just refresh the page to see if the default works (it will stay with which ever value is selected), you need to go back a page and re-click on the page again (or go click in the address bar and hit enter)

Answer (score 9):

```
 $this->Form->input('Leaf.id', array(
'type'=>'select',
'label'=>'Leaf',
'options'=>$leafs,
'value'=>2
));
```

This will select default second index position value from list of option in $leafs.

Answer (score 8):

the third parameter should be like array('selected' =>value)

Comment: This is only if you want that value to ALWAYS be selected

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using form helper to generate the form:

```
select(string $fieldName, array $options, mixed $selected, array $attributes, boolean $showEmpty)
```

Set the third parameter to set the selected option.

Comment: Hey, I have the following code:
    $options=array('1'=>'opt1','2'=>'opt2','3'=>'opt3');
    echo $form->select('Fieldname',$options , ??? ,array(),false);
whats the format for the 3rd parameter to set the selected item? I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: it should be the value of the selected option

Comment: In which version of CakePHP is this - I can't find documentation for this in either 1.1, 1.2 or 1.3?

Answer (score 1):

cakephp version >= 3.6

```
echo $this->Form->control('field_name', ['type' => 'select', 'options' => $departments, 'default' => 'your value']);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a text default in a select box use the `$form->select()` method. Here is how you do it.

```
$options = array('m'=>'Male','f'=>'Female','n'=>'neutral');

$form->select('Model.name',$options,'f');
```

The above code will select `Female` in the list box by default.

Keep baking...

Answer (score 0):

```
FormHelper::select(string $fieldName, array $options, 
array $attributes)
```

`$attributes['value']` to set which value should be selected default

```
<?php echo $this->Form->select('status', $list, array(
    'empty' => false, 
    'value' => 1)
); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cakephp version 3.0 and above, then you can add default value in select input using empty attribute as given in below example.

```
echo $this->Form->input('category_id', ['options'=>$categories,'empty'=>'Choose']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer to this could be

**Don't use selct for this job use input instead**

like this

```
echo  $this->Form->input('field_name', array(
          'type' => 'select',
            'options' => $options_arr, 
            'label' => 'label here',
            'value' => $id,  // default value
            'escape' => false,  // prevent HTML being automatically escaped
            'error' => false,
            'class' => 'form-control' // custom class you want to enter
        ));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As in CakePHP 4.2 the correct syntax for a select form element with a default value is quite simple:

```
echo $this->Form->select(
                'fieldname',
                ['value1', 
                'value2', 
                'value3'], 
                ['empty' => '(auswählen)','default'=>1]
            );
```

If hopefully don't need to explain the default=1 means the second value and default=0 means the first value. ;)

Be very careful with select values as it can get a little tricky. The example above is without specific values for the select fields, so its values get numerated automatically. If you set a specific value for each select list entry, and you want a default one, set its specific value:

```
$sizes = ['s' => 'Small', 
'm' => 'Medium', 
'l' => 'Large'];
echo $this->Form->select('size', $sizes, ['default' => 'm']);
```

This example is from the official 4.x Strawberry Cookbook.
https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-control

Answer (score -1):

For example, with a list of countries `"US" => "United States", ...`, this would work:

```php
<?=
$this->Form->select(
    'country',
    $countries,
    array(
        'onchange' => "setPostalRegex(this)",
        'onblur' => "selectStateMenu(this)",
        'val' => $country,
    )
);
?>
```

See: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-select-pickers