# Can I retrieve an aggregate column via the Containable behavior?

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp

Is it possible for CakePHP's Containable behavior to request an aggregate column value during a `find()`? For example, in model `Item` containing numeric columns `quarks` and `cogs`:

```
$this->Item->contain('quarks + cogs AS total');
```

Comment: This *should* work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592391/cakephp-mathematic-calculation-field/1592550#1592550

Comment: That definitely helps! Submit it as the answer, and I'll give you the checkmark. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright then...

This *should* work: [CakePHP mathematic-calculation field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592391/cakephp-mathematic-calculation-field/1592550#1592550)

:)